# videojs player not working on ipad

Tags: html5-video, video.js

we have installed the player on our web page using an html5 element design, however, the player fails to load the controls which allows the video to be played.

We do not have this problem on any Android device this is only effecting the iOS devices.

Here is a link to see the player we have implemented:

https://liveconferencepro.com/vp/viewHTML5.php?id=tah1pa

Can someone please tell us where we can obtain the correct code so the player will work for iOS devices?

Tom

Comment: Which versions of IOS have you tried it on?  It looks like that's the default video, so it should play.

Answer (score 0):

The player was broken for me in Chrome for multiple reasons. The first was that the link took me to the page served over SSL, but the Videojs includes were via http, which meant they were never loaded due to being insecure content.

Once I fixed that, I noticed this error in the console: `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<source' is not a valid attribute name.`

This seems to be because you didn't close the opening video tag:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="412" height="232" poster="https://liveconferencepro.com/vp/logo.jpg"
                    data-setup=""

    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
    ...
</video>
```

Finally, keep in mind that if you want to use custom controls on mobile, you'll need to enable custom controls. Due to idiosyncrasies in mobile devices, for now we've disabled custom controls by default, but you can set the option to `nativeControlForTouch: false` to disable this.

Hope that helps!